# Vuetify v-file-input with icon only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue, and Vuetify in particular.

I want to use the *v-file-input* component, but I want it to have only the paperclip icon without the text box. i tried to play with the css and the directives, but I didn't manage to do that.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/#file-inputs

[image]

with "hide-input"

[image]

We are adding **hide-input** to v-file-input (from v2.3.0-beta.6)

```
<v-file-input multiple label="File input" hide-input></v-file-input>
```

https://codepen.io/yipingruan/pen/ExPPozL

Comment: Thanks! is there a planned release date for the official v2.3.0 version? I see the milestone is 3 days overdue. Once the official release of this version will be published, I'll mark as the correct solution.

Comment: V2.3.0 is out, you can check https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

you can use `deep`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input multiple label="File input"></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>


//scss
#inspire {
  /deep/ {
    .v-input__control {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
//or
#inspire {
  ::v-deep {
    .v-input__control {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

demo:https://codepen.io/wzc570738205/pen/ZEQQKwm

this is doc:https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer,  but when I tried it, it threw an error:
```Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected selector.
   ╷
27 │   /deep/{
   │   ^
   ╵
  /Users/sshadur/WebstormProjects/vue-sandbox/src/App.vue 27:3  root stylesheet
```
Any idea why that could be?

Comment: use >>>  replace /deep/

Comment: #inspire >>> .v-input__control {
      display: none;
    }

Comment: this is scss not sass,if you get error ,you can try use >>>

Comment: Using `#inspire >>> .v-input__control { display: none; } ` doesn't raise an error, but the text box still remains...

Comment: `<style lang="scss">
  #inspire >>> .v-input__control { display: none; }

</style>`

Comment: #inspire {
  ::v-deep {
    .v-input__control {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215648/discussion-between-sagi-shadur-and-joinwang).